# $("a[rel=popover]").popover is not a function

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I call the `js` files for `bootstrap twitter` library but I get the error that indicates

```
$("a[rel=popover]").popover is not a function
```

.

```
<script src="../../jq/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../bootstrap/js/bootstrap-popover.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // second supervisor popover
        $('a[rel=popover]').popover({
            placement: 'below',
            offset: 20,
            trigger: 'manual'
        });
    });


</script>
```

Comment: Looks like the popover library hasnt loaded correctly, you sure the url is correct?

Comment: @Bader remove all the loose bootstrap plugin scripts and just keep the `bootstrap.js` script intact, that script file comes with all of the plugins already included inside.

Comment: @Bader can you post a link to your site? I'm sure that some assets might be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

<strike>http://jsfiddle.net/9W53Q/7/</strike>

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/9W53Q/272/

Make sure the resoures are being added in the right order (tooltip first).
Or like Richard Dalton suggested (and I recommend), just use the compiled bootstrap.js file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[rel=popover]').popover();
});
```

Comment: Given it's a 2 year old example the JSHint Bootstrap references were no longer available, please make sure you check the date on answers as the problem was fairly obvious.  I've updated to the latest versions.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me in ASP.NET MVC 4.  In my project I had a

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

both at the top of my page in the `<head>` and then again one of these little `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` suckers snuck in towards the end of the page just before the `</body>`.  I removed the redundant line at the end of the page and the problem went away.

Note that the browser rendered the `<head>` in the correct order:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js">
<script src="/twitterBootstrap/js/bootstrap.js">
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js">
```

However, I ended up with another

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js">
```

at the bottom of the page.  This confused the browser and it confused the heck outta me too.